# Replacing a word in a text file using C

Tags: c

I am writing a c program that takes a text file and reads through the file searching for a specified word. The program then replaces the word with another chosen word. The problem I have is that using fgets replaces the whole line and not just the chosen word. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
This is the block of code.

```
while (fgets(ch, 20, ifp) != NULL){

    if (strstr(ch, argv[2]) != 0)
    {
        fputs(argv[3], ofp);
    }
    else
    {
        fputs(ch, ofp);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - Replacing words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186734/c-replacing-words)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574583/c-program-copy-text-from-stdin-to-stdout/28574709#28574709 C program - copy text from stdin to stdout.  Did this homework assignment just get posted or something?